# Android code throwing errors

Tags: android, compiler-errors

This is some code for an app that will just print hello world to my phone. However, when I try to change the text from "@string/hello_world" to something else (eg "@string/hello") in the Android studio it throws an error. Can anyone help?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Have u added the string `hello` in `strings.xml`? Go to `strings.xml` in `res -> values ->strings.xml` open it. there you find a line `<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>`

Comment: What is that (this is the first time I'm using this)

Comment: If u mean in this <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" yes

Comment: Kindly read this documents https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicNetworking/res/values/strings.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html and understand the purpose of `String Resources` and try it out. It will help you to go further. On that `TextView` hold `CTRL + CLICK` on `"@string/hello_world"` will take you to `strings.xml` there you can create and modify `String Resources`

Comment: This says if you want to give a `android:text="@string/myapp"` then in `strings.xml` should have `<string name="myapp">Hey, This is My App</string>`. So in `TextView` it displays `Hey, This is My App`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your res folder -> values -> strings.xml.

In that file you can find the string name and values.

Just change the name and value whatever you want and give that name in the layout.

```
<string name="Hello_world">Hello World</string>
```

to

```
<string name="Hello">My First Application</string>
```